# add id prefix to css rule generated from Emotion 11

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, emotion

I am using Emotion 11 as css-in-js lib for a React project.

My goal is to generate styles with a given prefix to the selector in order to increase specifity (the pages also include legacy css).

```
.c50id {
  color: pink;
}
```

to

```
#my-chosen-id .c50id {
  color: pink;
}
```

I found questions suggesting to use `stylis-plugin-extra-scope` but it does not seem to work anymore due to the upgrade to stylis 4.

Any suggestion is welcomed,
thank you!

Comment: Hey, I got stuck with the same issue, How did you solve this?